# Triangle Inequality for $\|x\|_{\infty}$

Tags: analysis, inequality, normed-spaces, triangles

I have to show the triangle inequality for $\|x\|_{\infty}$. I'm not sure, if estimate is correct. To show: $\|x+y\|_{\infty} \le \|x\|_{\infty}+\|y\|_{\infty}$

Let $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $\|x\|_{\infty}=\max\{|x_1|,\dots,|x_n|\}$:

$\|x+y\|_{\infty}=\max\{|x_1+y_1|,\dots,|x_n+y_n|\} \le \max\{|x_1|+|y_1|,\dots,|x_n|+|y_n|\} \le \max\{|x_1|,\dots,|x_n|\} +\max\{|y_1|,\dots,|y_n|\} \, \square$

Unfortunately I haven't any other appropriate ideas. Thanks for help!

Comment: Your proof is perfectly correct.

Comment: It's not clear why the second inequality holds. It has the appearance of you just having written down the result that you want to show. Perhaps you need to do something that leaves less room for doubt. For example, you could try using induction.

Comment: @Dark The proof is pretty far from "perfectly correct". It has the right idea, sure, but the last equality needs to be proven.

Comment: By the way , what is a triangle equation  !!  Did you mean triangle inequality  ? Does it hold for all  $x$ and  $y$ ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proof is fine. But if you do not find it convincing yet this might mean you should add more details.

For example, you could justify the last inequality a bit more by saying that for each $j$ one has $|x_j| \le \max\{|x_1|,...,|x_n|\}$ and $|y_j| \le \max\{|y_1|,...,|y_n|\} $ and thus $|x_j|+|y_j| \le \max\{|x_1|,...,|x_n|\} +\max\{|y_1|,...,|y_n|\} $.

Comment: I don't see the proof as fine. OP only wrote the definition of the infinity norm, then wrote down what he wants to show. The bulk of the exercise is proving the last inequality, which is left unproven.

Comment: Your paraphrase is not complete. There is an additional step in OP, you did not mention, namely the first inequality. However, I agree that some more justification could be added, which is why I had included it in my answer.

Comment: OK, so some of the proof is there, sure. But less than half, and certainly less than what one would need for the proof to be "fine"

Comment: In my mind the proof is fine, in that it uses the (or at least a) correct strategy. How many details are needed to achieve a sufficient level of rigor is hard to know, and a matter of opinion. Yet, certainly, if OP is not convinced by their own argument they should add some, which again is why I provided those details. I am a bit astonished that you do not talk to the user that said  "[the] proof is perfectly correct."